# Fetch values from an array using nested foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a long array from which I wish to fetch all the values and store it in a separate variable, and store each value in database.

The array that I have is:

```
 Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 39
                    [name] => BAGS
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 59
                                    [name] => Handcrafted Purses
                                    [categories] => 
                                    [status] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 45
                                    [parent_id] => 39
                                    [name] => Laptop Bag
                                    [categories] => 
                                    [status] => 1
                                )
                        )
                    [status] => 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 40
                    [name] => BOXERS
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 56
                                    [parent_id] => 40
                                    [name] =>  Women Boxers
                                    [status] => 1
                                )
                        )
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 91
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => Business Corporate
                    [image] => 
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 92
                                    [parent_id] => 91
                                    [name] => Bags
                                    [image] => 
                                    [categories] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 93
                                                    [parent_id] => 92
                                                    [name] => Potli Bags
                                                    [image] => 
                                                    [categories] => 
                                                    [status] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [status] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [status] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 60
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => Business Corporates
                    [image] => 
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 90
                                    [parent_id] => 60
                                    [name] => Art Cushions
                                    [image] => 
                                    [categories] => 
                                    [status] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 67
                                    [parent_id] => 60
                                    [name] => Bags
                                    [image] => 
                                    [categories] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 77
                                                    [parent_id] => 67
                                                    [name] => Potli Bags
                                                    [image] => 
                                                    [categories] => 
                                                    [status] => 1
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 76
                                                    [parent_id] => 67
                                                    [name] => Smart Bags
                                                    [image] => 
                                                    [categories] => 
                                                    [status] => 1
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [status] => 1
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 86
                                    [parent_id] => 60
                                    [name] => Fashion Jewellery
                                    [image] => 
                                    [categories] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 88
                                                    [parent_id] => 86
                                                    [name] => Coming Soon - Products Uploading
                                                    [image] => 
                                                    [categories] => 
                                                    [status] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [status] => 1
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 61
                                    [parent_id] => 60
                                    [name] => Men Footwear
                                    [image] => 
                                    [categories] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 65
                                                    [parent_id] => 61
                                                    [name] => Canvas Loafers
                                                    [image] => 
                                                    [categories] => 
                                                    [status] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [status] => 1
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 87
                                    [parent_id] => 60
                                    [name] => Shawls And Stoles
                                    [image] => 
                                    [categories] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 89
                                                    [parent_id] => 87
                                                    [name] => Coming Soon - Products Uploading
                                                    [image] => 
                                                    [categories] => 
                                                    [status] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [status] => 1
                                )
                        )

                    [status] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 15
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => ETHNIC WEAR 
                    [image] => 
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 28
                                    [parent_id] => 15
                                    [name] => Designer Lehngas
                                    [image] => 
                                    [categories] => 
                                    [status] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 2
                                    [parent_id] => 15
                                    [name] => Suits
                                    [image] => 
                                    [categories] => 
                                    [status] => 1
                                )
                        )

                    [status] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

I am able to fetch the outer values of this array by using this code:

```
if (!empty($array)) 
    {
        foreach ($array['categories'] as $category) 
            {
                echo $category['category_id'];
                echo "<br>";
            }
    }
```

I got values as:

```
39
40
91
60
15
16
38
57
```

But I also wish to access the inner most values of the array. Can anyone tell how I can create a nested loop?

Comment: Take a look at recursion. It will allow you to traverse n-dimentional array. You should able to find tutorials around the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you now how deep your array is you can just simply add other foreach-loops within your main loop.

```
if (!empty($array)) 
{
    foreach ($array['categories'] as $category) 
        {
            echo $category['category_id'];
            echo "<br>";

            if(isset($category['categories'])){
            foreach($category['categories'] as $category2)
                {
                echo $category2['category_id'];
                echo "<br>";

                     if (isset($category2['categories'])){
                     foreach($category2['categories'] as $category3)
                       {
                         echo $category3['category_id'];
                         echo "<br>";

                         ...

                       } }

                }}
        }
}
```

Comment: i tried you way but when i started looping for and after category3 i started getting an error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for every new category in it

Comment: Well, within your main array with the index 1, the last child array has no such field "categories". So you can make sure that all of your arrays have this field "categories" or you first check whether this field exists.

Comment: in index 1 i do not have but in index 2 i do have it, can u plz tel me how i can sort it out..