# getting incorrect values while fetching values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I need to fetch values from an array, for this i tried to refer the code given here at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473537/fetch-values-from-an-array-using-nested-foreach-loop)

the array that i have is

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 405
                    [name] => GOLD CHID
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 39
                            [1] => 59
                        )
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 404
                    [name] => KASHMIRI
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 39
                            [1] => 59
                        )
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 403
                    [name] => ENVELOPE BOX
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 39
                            [2] => 59
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

the code that i used to fetch the array is

```
if (!empty($array)) 
    {
        foreach ($array['products'] as $product) 
            {
                echo $product['id'];
                echo "<br>";
                echo $product['name'];
                echo "<br>";

                    if(isset($product['categories']))
                        {
                            foreach($product['categories'] as $category)
                            echo $category['0'];
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo $category['1'];
                            echo "<br>";
                        }
            } 
    }
```

i a mgetting proper values of id and name, however i am not getting proper result for `$category['0']` and `$category['1']`

the result that i got is

```
405
GOLD CHID
35
9

404
KASHMIRI
35
9

403
ENVELOPE BOX
35
9
```

Can anyone tell me where i went wrong???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from a couple of issues.

- Firstly, you don't wrap your 2nd `foreach` loop in braces
- Secondly, you are iterating over the categories when your code isn't expecting that.

Your code:

```
foreach($product['categories'] as $category)
echo $category['0'];
echo "<br>";
echo $category['1'];
echo "<br>";
```

Is effectively:

```
foreach($product['categories'] as $category) {
    echo $category['0'];
}
echo "<br>";
echo $category['1'];
echo "<br>";
```

Which loops over each category, printing the 1st charater in each (`35`), then it prints the 2nd character in the last category (`9`).

Change it to the following:

```
foreach($product['categories'] as $category) {
    echo $category;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your ans, in echo $category; i get the values but i wish to store them separately in database, is there a way, where i can fetch the values 39, 59 in seperate variables???

Comment: Yes, don't use the `foreach` loop and refer to them as `$product['categories'][0]` and `$product['categories'][1]`.

Comment: can u plz tel me what if there are different number of categories in [0] and [1]. In for each loop i assigned $category['0'] as main category and $category['1'] as sub category, but now when i go furthur down in the array, I have 3 position within category at [0], [1] and[2] position and [1] is holding value of category and [2] is holding value of subcategory. How can i get the values of category now???

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
foreach($product['categories'] as $category)
{
echo $category['0'];
echo "<br>";
echo $category['1'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

to this

```
foreach($product['categories'] as $category)
{
 echo $category;
 echo "<br>";
 echo $category;
 echo "<br>";
}
```

because in your code `$category[0]` will output 0th element in `35`. and $category will give the actual value

Comment: i am getting repetitive values of 39 and 59 for a single product, whereas i wish to store them seperately in a variable only once for each product