# Fetch values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am getting an array from the following code

```
$classes = $mb->makeNumericArray($data['GetClassesResult']['Classes']['Class']);
$result = $classes;

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
```

and the array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ClassScheduleID] => 
            [ClassDescription] => Array
                (
                    [Description] => 
                    [Program] => Array
                        (
                            [ScheduleType] => DropIn
                        )
                )

            [Staff] => Array
                (
                    [SortOrder] => 
                }
        )   

     [1] => Array
        (
            [ClassScheduleID] => 
            [ClassDescription] => Array
                (
                    [Description] => 
                    [Program] => Array
                        (
                            [ScheduleType] => DropIn
                        )
                )

            [Staff] => Array
                (
                    [SortOrder] => 
                }
        )   
)
```

I tried to fetch the code taking  the reference from this [code at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473537/fetch-values-from-an-array-using-nested-foreach-loop),

```
foreach($result as $res)
    {
        $classscheduleid= $res['ClassScheduleID'];
        echo $classscheduleid;

    }
```

At the present I tried this code, to print the `ClassScheduleID`.

But it is not fetching the data properly. It misses the values at `[0]` and in rest of the array it repeats the result.

Can anyone tell me how I can fetch `ClassScheduleID` along with `Description`, `ScheduleType` and `sortorder` from the complete array?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are not mixing `result` and  `classes` are you? Is there any code that mutates result into classes and influence the data set?

Comment: @mvbrakel i have edited the question and the 2 values are not mixing, can u plz go thru it again

Comment: I see you edited the question to show how classes is mutated to results. I upvoted n-dru's edited answer. That should do the trick. Only in his answer replace `classes` with `results` to conform to your updated question

Comment: @mvbrakel it it i can store class schedule id in database but i am not able to save others in db as they are displayed in simple text

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over internal array:

```
foreach($classes as $key => $internal_array){
    $classscheduleid= $internal_array['ClassScheduleID'];
    echo $classscheduleid;
    //again, ClassDescription is also array
    foreach($internal_array['ClassDescription'] as $internal_key => $res){

       echo " $internal_key => $res";//etc

    }
}
```

Or do it recursively:

```
function echo_array($a, $key){
    foreach($a as $key1 => $array1){
        if(!is_array($array1)){
            echo "$key $key1 : $array1<br/>";
        }else{
            echo_array($array1,$key1);
        }
    }
}
echo_array($a,'');
```

Comment: Does this work? When i look at the code it seems like `$res['ClassScheduleID'];` will not exist? Am i missing something? `ClassScheduleID` is a key in the `$internal_array` loop is it not?

Comment: @n-dru i am getting result like this 0 => 0 => 0

Comment: @n-dru i am getting the result now but not in the form i wish, as i neewd each value seperately so that i can save each one of them in database

Comment: Well you are now asking for real basic PHP. Replace the `echo` command with the assignment to a variable of your choosing. With that you can then create a save command the way you would like

Comment: you can create new array with the keys by which you want to store the values and in place of echo just push those values to that array.

Comment: @n-dru i tried doing like this $ImageURL= $res['ImageURL'];echo $ImageURL; but it gave me o/p as h T < 2, can u plz tell me where i went wrong

Comment: @st001 I can't see this value in your array. I edited my answer with recursive way of echoing the keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `foreach ($result as $row)`
then you will loop through all $result[0], $result[1]...
then you echo `$result[0]["ClassScheduleID"]` wich in you case, look at `print_r ($result)`, is emptry so that's why you don't get a result.

Comment: i have modified the question can u plz go thru it once again, as my array is having value